# Form Authentication with LDAP

Tags: java, authentication, ldap, quarkus

I'm facing an error when trying to authenticate a user using form autentication, that does not happen when using basic athentication.
*quarkus.http.auth.form.enabled=false*

Everything works fine using basic authentication but when a change the property to true
*quarkus.http.auth.form.enabled=true*

then a get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'credential' may not be null
        at org.wildfly.common.Assert.checkNotNullParamChecked(Assert.java:71)
        at org.wildfly.common.Assert.checkNotNullParam(Assert.java:49)
        at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.ServerAuthenticationContext.addPrivateCredential(ServerAuthenticationContext.java:798)
        at io.quarkus.elytron.security.runtime.ElytronTrustedIdentityProvider$1.get(ElytronTrustedIdentityProvider.java:55)
        at io.quarkus.elytron.security.runtime.ElytronTrustedIdentityProvider$1.get(ElytronTrustedIdentityProvider.java:43)
        at io.quarkus.security.runtime.QuarkusIdentityProviderManagerImpl$1$1$1$1.run(QuarkusIdentityProviderManagerImpl.java:58)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$13.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:543)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

this is the only change in the application.properties.

In the console I can see that the user is found in LDAP but it crashes with this error.

quarkus version 2.3.0-Final,
I`ve upgraded it to 2.4.1.Final and I found the same behavior

******* UPDATE**
I've created a repository with an example based on quarkus-security-jdbc

but this one is using LDAP and Form based

https://github.com/hikemachado/quarkus-ldap-quickstart

---

Thank you all

Comment: Looks like there was a fix made 2021-11-09 https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/21307

Comment: hi Begui, I opened the issue. Quarkus team fixed and closed  it yesterday. I forgot to update here , thanks a lot.